# TelephonyManager.getNetworkType() and HSDPA problems :(

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have been using the following code to establish which network the device is using :

```
TelephonyManager tempManager;
tempManager= (TelephonyManager)myContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int result = 0;
    if(tempManager != null && tempManager.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS) //do we have a UMTS connection ?
  {
   result = 2;
  }
  else if(tempManager != null && tempManager.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS) //or is it just a shabby 2g connection ?
  {
   result = 1;
  }
  else if(tempManager != null && tempManager.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN) //or is it just a shabby 2g connection ?
  {
   result = 4;
  }
return result;
```

It works pretty well unless I get on a HSDPA connection, in that case it will always return 0 as a result, which in my case makes my software think it has no connection at all :(

Anyone who knows whats happening, has some experience regarding this and most importantly has some solution to this problem ???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a enum also for [HSDPA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA)

To check if there is connection and also get a type, I would rather user [getActiveNetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29) and [isConnected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#isConnected%28%29). It returns null when there is no connection. You can also check the type of connection by [getType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getType%28%29) and [getSubtypeName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getSubtypeName%28%29) methods or you can mix with your approach.

Comment: hhhmmm, damn that explains a lot ! it's there since api level 5 :( I made a 1.6 project which obviously doesn't recognize it :(

Comment: :) You can use newer API. It is just a static const, so it will work on older devices.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using. It will safely check for a connection and then return the connection type. For my application, I only care about Wifi, Mobile, or not connected so that is what this function will return. Change for your own situation.

```
//Check weather Internet connection is available or not
public int checkConnectionType()
{
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isAvailable() && activeNetInfo.isConnected())
    {
        int type = activeNetInfo.getType();
        if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE || type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_DUN
                || type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI || type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_MMS
                || type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_SUPL || type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX)
        {
            return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
        }
        else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
        {
            return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        }
        else
        {
            // Unknown connection type, so to be safe say mobile
            return ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // return not connected
        return -1;
    }
}
```

You will need this permission in your app's manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```